# Any books on Trigonometrical Sums (for the Theory of Numbers )?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

All:

Can anyone recommend good books on Trigonometrical Sums ? The only book I found is 
Vinogradov's book: Method of Trigonometrical Sums in the Theory of Numbers. 
but it is really old.

I am looking for a newer book, cover some recent progress in this area, (prefer easy to read).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Trigonometric Sums in Number Theory and Analysis by Arkhipov, Chubarikov and Karatsuba](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110162660)